# c++ program to print a horizontal bar chart

Tags: c++

I want to print a chart by taking integers from console. I have come up with this syntax. Stuck at a conditional statement.

```
int main() {

    int array[10];
    int num;
    int size = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        if(num == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        array[i] = num;
        size++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(*something goes here*) 
                cout << "*";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    int values[MAX];
    int size = 0;
    while (true) {
        int num;
        cin >> num;

        if (num == 0) break;
        else values[size++] = num;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i]; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer to not using vector

Comment: If you look closely, you also don't need that `find_largest` method

Comment: @Pinak Das Next time you can break the problem down, which would then become "How to print n number of stars?" instead of dumping your unformatted code on us.

Comment: *"Can you modify the code without using vector. I am in the initial stages of my c++ learning."* - A vector is about the most basic C++ thing for "a collection of things". It is a perfect fit for all and any "collection of things" needs in initial stages of C++ learning.

Comment: Just reverse the first loop. So, instead of `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`, you should change it to `for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)`